# How can I hide bottom separator in some UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, separator

I'm developing an app using UITableView Grouped Style and I want to hide some cells bottomSeparator but I don't know how.

This is the result I want :
[Result I want](http://img198.imageshack.us/img198/1852/capture1jh.png)

I've tried this :

```
[self.tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];
[self.tableView setSeparatorColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

and this :

```
UIImageView *line = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12, HEIGHT_ROW_HEADER, 320-(12*2), 1)];
line.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[cell addSubview:line];
```

But I don't have borders around UItableView

I have a thing like this :
[Result I have](http://img208.imageshack.us/img208/3927/capture2vw.png)

Someone can help me ?

Thank you a lot

Comment: what you want... you want border around your table view?

Comment: seems perfect if only HEIGHT_ROW_HEADER is proper.

Comment: Yes HEIGHT_ROW_HEADER is proper but I want border around my table view

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24574/objective-c-discussion come to this room for discussion

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to remove `SeparatorColor` and `setSeparatorStyle`.

```
[self.tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];
[self.tableView setSeparatorColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

then check if your cell is last cell of section then you need to add image in cell.

```
viewNormal=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 59, cell.frame.size.width, 1)];

UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
btn.frame = viewNormal.bounds;
btn.enabled = NO;
[btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"lineBgImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[viewNormal addSubview:btn];


[cell addSubview:viewNormal];
```

and remove `viewNormal` for other cell. I am adding separator like this way and working fine for. Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks Nirav but in your solution I don't have border around my table view and I want it.

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24574/objective-c-discussion come to this room.

Comment: I can't, I need 20 reputation :/ sorry